# git add . not working, but git add filename.js works, why and how can I fix it?

Tags: git

Here are the results:

When I execute `git add .`, the terminal is not responding. I have to use Ctrl+C to get back.

When I execute `git add filename.js`, it works successfully. This hasn't happened before. Why and how do I fix it?

```
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  modified:   app.js
  modified:   workers.js
  modified:   templates/index.pug
  modified:   utils.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ git add . 
^C
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ git add workers.js 
➜  myproject git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

  modified:   workers.js

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

  modified:   app.js
  modified:   templates/index.pug
  modified:   utils.js
```

Update:

I have waited more than 3 minutes after `git add .`, it used to be super fast.

Git version: `2.17.1`

Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Why is there a `^C` after `git add .` ? There shouldn't be anything to interrupt when staging.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's going on here, but: (1) how long did you wait before ^C-ing, (2) what OS and Git version are you using, and (3) what file system are you using? If you're in a VM with a remote mounted file system, where is the server? If you're in a Dropbox folder, be careful as Dropbox and Git will "fight" and things will go wrong.

Comment: If you suspect `git add .` may be hanging on something as I do, you might try pressing `Ctrl-Z` rather than `Ctrl-C`.  That will usually send a STOP signal and then you can run `ps` to see what programs are running as subprocesses of `git`, if any. `lsof` is good for looking at open sockets if you suspect `git` itself is trying to do something.  . `fg` will bring the command to the foreground again.

Comment: @GinoMempin Because I wait for a very long time without and responding.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Thanks for the tip. I never knew Ctrl+Z would work this way. Thanks

Comment: Wow. I know of no bugs of this sort in Git 2.17, and 3 minutes is typically plenty of time. The fact that `git status` can traverse the file system tree indicates that it's not a directory-tree-walk issue either. The most likely candidate would be some kind of filter operation that's going wrong (e.g., if you're using Git-LFS).

Comment: is your git repository located in a regular local filesystem (e.g : not sshfs, or a shared drive ...) ? is it in a synced directory (ownCloud, dropbox ...) ?

Answer (score 1):

To debug your issue : git allows you to have more insight on what it is doing if you active some environment variables (full list [in the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging)) :

```
GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 git add .
```

You can also use `strace` :

```
strace git add .
# you can dump it in a file (strace prints on stderr by default) :
sttace git add . 2> git_add.strace
# you can add timing information :
strace -tt -T git add . 2> git_add.strace
```

it will at least show you all the gory details on what files `git add .` tries to access.